# Understanding the difference between f() and f(void) in C and C++ once and for all

Tags: c++, c, function, void

Ok, so I have heard different opinions on this subject and just want to make sure I understand it correctly.

### For C++

Declarations `void f();` and `void f(void);` mean precisely the same thing, the function `f` does not take any parameters. Ditto for definitions.

### For C

Declaration `void f(void);` means that `f` does not take any parameters.

Declaration `void f();` means that function `f` may or may not have parameters, and if it does, we don't know what kind of parameters those are, or how many there is of them. Note that it is NOT the same as ellipsis, we can't use `va_list`.

Now here is where things get interesting.

#### Case 1

Declaration:

```
void f();
```

Definition:

```
void f(int a, int b, float c)
{
   //...
}
```

#### Case 2

Declaration:

```
void f();
```

Definition:

```
void f()
{
   //...
}
```

#### Question:

What happens at compile time in cases 1 and 2 when we call `f` with the correct arguments, wrong arguments and no arguments at all? What happens at run time?

#### Additional question:

If I declare `f` with arguments, but define it without them, will it make a difference? Should I be able to address the arguments from the function body?

Comment: in **C** `void f();` is the same as `void f(void);`. In one you are **implicitly** saying "no arguments" (the compiler infers this) and in the other one you are **explicitly** saying "no arguments". Also it is better if you try those examples on your own, so you get more comfortable while using the compiler later on.

Comment: @Dietrich (this is something I did not know till now, thanks) but as paxdiablo pointed out this only occurs when declaring,  I meant when _defining_ a function . Oh well, http://pastebin.com/MqhDBZg1 this link a program someone can try to make sense out of this (as I did :))

Comment: AFAIK in C99 void f(); is the same as void f(void);
// correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @paxdiablo `void f();` is not a prototype (it's a declaration which is not a prototype).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

More terminology (C, not C++): a prototype for a function declares the types of its arguments.  Otherwise the function does not have a prototype.

```
void f();                      // Declaration, but not a prototype
void f(void);                  // Declaration and prototype
void f(int a, int b, float c); // Declaration and prototype
```

Declarations that aren't prototypes are holdovers from pre-ANSI C, from the days of K&R C.  The only reason to use an old-style declaration is to maintain binary compatibility with old code.  For example, in [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK) 2 there is a function declaration without a prototype -- it is there by accident, but it can't be removed without breaking binaries.  The C99 standard comments:

> 6.11.6 Function declarators

> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
> type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

**Recommendation:** I suggest compiling all C code in GCC/Clang with `-Wstrict-prototypes` and `-Wmissing-prototypes`, in addition to the usual `-Wall -Wextra`.

### What happens

```
void f(); // declaration
void f(int a, int b, float c) { } // ERROR
```

The declaration disagrees with the function body!  This is actually a *compile time* error, and it's because you can't have a `float` argument in a function without a prototype.  The reason you can't use a `float` in an unprototyped function is because when you call such a function, all of the arguments get promoted using certain default promotions.  Here's a fixed example:

```
void f();

void g()
{
    char a;
    int b;
    float c;
    f(a, b, c);
}
```

In this program, `a` is promoted to `int`<sup>1</sup> and `c` is promoted to `double`.  So the definition for `f()` has to be:

```
void f(int a, int b, double c)
{
    ...
}
```

See C99 6.7.6 paragraph 15,

> If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a
> function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty
> identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each
> parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the
> default argument promotions.

### Answer 1

> What happens at compile time in cases 1 and 2 when we call `f` with the correct arguments, wrong arguments and no arguments at all? What happens at run time?

When you call `f()`, the parameters get promoted using the default promotions.  If the promoted types match the actual parameter types for `f()`, then all is good.  If they don't match, it will *probably* compile but you will definitely get undefined behavior.

"Undefined behavior" is spec-speak for "we make no guarantees about what will happen."  Maybe your program will crash, maybe it will work fine, maybe it will invite your in-laws over for dinner.

There are two ways to get diagnostics at compile-time.  If you have a sophisticated compiler with cross-module static analysis capabilities, then you will probably get an error message.  You can also get messages for un-prototyped function declarations with GCC, using `-Wstrict-prototypes` -- which I recommend turning on in all your projects (except for files which use GTK 2).

### Answer 2

> If I declare `f` with arguments, but define it without them, will it make a difference? Should I be able to address the arguments from the function body?

It shouldn't compile.

### Exceptions

There are actually two cases in which function arguments are allowed to disagree with the function definition.

1. It is okay to pass `char *` to a function that expects `void *`, and vice versa.
2. It is okay to pass a signed integer type to a function that expects the unsigned version of that type, or vice versa, as long as the value is representable in both types (i.e., it is not negative, and not out of range of the signed type).

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>: It is *possible* that `char` promotes to `unsigned int`, but this is very uncommon.

Comment: "What happens" is dead wrong - you do _NOT_ get an error, not should you.

Comment: @paxdiablo: But I do get an error.  GCC: error: conflicting types for ‘f’; note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Error occurs in GCC 4.0, 4.2, and 4.7, as well as Clang 3.1.

Comment: You should read the error more closely. It has nothing to do with the empty list per se. It's to do with your chosen arguments (the float). It disallows arguments with a default promotion (float->double). You'll find that if you change that float to an int or double, your error disappears.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm sorry, I thought that was exactly what I was saying.  Look at the second example, which changes the type to `double`.

Comment: That's better, you're making it clear _why_ there was an error. Perhaps I misunderstood your original contention.

Answer (score 7):

The whole thing is really a moot point if you're using C99 or later (and, unless you're stuck on an old embedded system or something like that, you probably *should* be using something more modern).

C99/C11 section `6.11.6 Future language directions, Function declarators` states:

> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

Hence you should avoid using things like `void f();` altogether.

If it takes parameters, list them, forming a proper prototype. If not, use `void` to indicate definitively that it doesn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, f() and f(void) are same.

In C, they are different and any number of arguments can be passed while calling the f() function, but no argument can be passed in f(void).

Answer (score -2):

In pure C, this results in the error: `error C2084: function 'void __cdecl f(void )' already has a body`

```
void f(void);
void f();

int main() {
  f(10);
  f(10.10);
  f("ten");

  return 0;
}

void f(void) {

}

void f() {

}
```

> fvoid.c line(19) : error C2084: function 'void __cdecl f(void )' already has a body

But in *pure* C++, it will compile without errors.

**Overloading functions (C++ only, C has no overloading)**

You overload a function name f by declaring more than one function with the name f in the same scope. The declarations of f must differ from each other by the types and/or the number of arguments in the argument list. When you call an overloaded function named f, the correct function is selected by comparing the argument list of the function call with the parameter list of each of the overloaded candidate functions with the name f.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int i);
void f(double  f);
void f(char* c);


int main() {
  f(10);
  f(10.10);
  f("ten");

  return 0;
}

void f(int i) {
  cout << " Here is int " << i << endl;
}
void f(double  f) {
  cout << " Here is float " << f << endl;
}

void f(char* c) {
  cout << " Here is char* " << c << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Here is int 10
Here is float 10.1
Here is char* ten
```

Comment: So... what does this have to do with the difference between `void f();` and `void f(void);` ?

Comment: void f(void)  is the correct way to say "no parameters" in C. But void f( ) will do just as fine

Comment: This question is mostly about C, is it not? C has no overloading.

Comment: "But void f( ) will do just as fine.": no, not in C.

Comment: the difference between void f(); and void f(void) -> In pure C, this results in the error: error C2084: function 'void __cdecl f(void )' already has a body. In C++, it's just function overloading.

Comment: The first program has several compilation errors in C++. The second program has nothing to do with the question.