# "Candidate function not viable;" Issues with porting a C library to C++

Tags: c++, c, porting

I'm attempting to use a c library in a c++ implementation, and I get errors often having to do with "cantidate function not viable," and it appears to think that the function in the library will not function with the arguments presented in my code. The thing is, my code is literally an old implementation (in c) that works perfectly fine when compiled in c. Is there a way to make this compile as a part of my c++ environment?

Here are the errors I get:

```
testbed/des-lsr_routinglogic.cpp:20:27: error: no matching function for call to 'dessert_periodic_add'
periodic_refresh_nh = dessert_periodic_add(refresh_list, NULL, NULL, &refresh_neighbor_t);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/dessert.h:880:21: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'dessert_per_result_t ()' to 'dessert_periodiccallback_t *' (aka 'dessert_per_result_t (*)(void *, struct
  timeval *, struct timeval *)') for 1st argument
dessert_periodic_t* dessert_periodic_add(dessert_periodiccallback_t* c, void* data, const struct timeval* scheduled, const struct timeval* interval);
                ^
```

from this line of code code:

```
periodic_refresh_nh = dessert_periodic_add(refresh_list, NULL, NULL, &refresh_neighbor_t);
```

using this excerpt of the library:

```
dessert_periodic_t* dessert_periodic_add(dessert_periodiccallback_t* c, void* data,     const struct timeval* scheduled, const struct timeval* interval);
dessert_periodic_t* dessert_periodic_add_delayed(dessert_periodiccallback_t* c, void* data, int delay);
int dessert_periodic_del(dessert_periodic_t* p);
void dessert_register_ptr_name(void* ptr, const char* name);
const char* dessert_ptr2name(void* ptr);
```

I think the compiler output should be self evident to anyone experienced in combining c/c++ but it looks like gibberish to me D:

### EDIT

Thank you, it was pointed out to me I left out some important definitions;
The definition of refresh_list:

```
 dessert_per_result_t refresh_list(void *data, struct timeval *scheduled, struct timeval *interval) {
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&pp_rwlock);
node_neighbors_t *neighbor = dir_neighbors_head;
while (neighbor) {
    if (neighbor->entry_age-- == 0) {
        node_neighbors_t* el_to_delete = neighbor;
        HASH_DEL(dir_neighbors_head, el_to_delete);
        free(el_to_delete);
    } else {
        neighbor->weight = 1;
    }
    neighbor = neighbor->hh.next;
}
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&pp_rwlock);
return 0; }
```

The definition of dessert_per_result_t:

```
 typedef enum _dessert_periodic_results { DESSERT_PER_KEEP = 0, DESSERT_PER_UNREGISTER = 1 } dessert_per_result_t;
```

dessert_periodiccallback_t is defined oddly; I will try to post it.

Comment: While the compiler output is fairly easy to understand, it's totally obscure to us what `refresh_list` is, because you chose not to tell us.

Comment: Please also post the declarations of `dessert_periodiccallback_t`, `dessert_per_result_t` and `refresh_list`.

Comment: You are passing a structure and the library expects a pointer. Ah, we all *love*, C, huh?

Comment: typedef enum _dessert_periodic_results {
    DESSERT_PER_KEEP = 0,
    DESSERT_PER_UNREGISTER = 1
} dessert_per_result_t;

Comment: @KerrekSB: `refresh_list` has type `dessert_per_result_t ()`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Errr.. clearly not, given the code you just posted.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I did not post any code. However, my assertion is consistent with the code posted by Grey Newell. And the type of `result_list` is shown to us in the compiler error message.

Comment: @GreyNewell: you have shown the definition of `result_list`. However, the problem is its declaration in a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is stricter about function declarations than C. In this case, the function `refresh_list` is declared as `dessert_per_result_t refresh_list()`, but the first argument to `dessert_periodic_add` must be a pointer to a function with explicitly specified parameter types.

The best way to fix this would be to add a complete declaration of `refresh_list`, matching what `dessert_periodic_add` expects, in place of the abbreviated declaration of it.

Comment: Thanks to David Foerster for the correction. I was scrolling back and forth on a small device to copy text and compose an answer.

Comment: Now I just need to ask the creator of the library what in the hell I should pass as params in a function I don't know when I want to call without global variables... oh, c...

Comment: @GreyNewell: Global variables are not an issue. The parameter type is. The parameter type is shown: `dessert_periodic_add` expects a pointer to a function taking two parameters, the first a pointer to `void` and the other two pointers to `struct timeval *`, and returning `dessert_per_result_t`. So `refresh_list` should be declared as `dessert_per_result_t refresh_list(void *, struct
  timeval *, struct timeval *)`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message shows that the compiler is of the opinion that `refresh_list` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `dessert_per_result_t`.

The definition you posted disagrees.

This suggests that there is a separate declaration of `refresh_list` that is inconsistent with the definition.

Comment: The declaration may be inconsistent in C++ but not in C.

Comment: Very possible, yes. In which case he might have to modify the library headers.

Comment: I would like to avoid modifying headers if possible as my library is used in several places in this project.

Comment: Well, is refresh_list your own function, or part of the library?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `refresh_list` shown in the error message is this:

```
dessert_per_result_t refresh_list();
```

This means two different things in C++ and C.

In C++, it means that `refresh_list` takes zero arguments.

In C, it means that `refresh_list` takes an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified types.

Hence why it worked in C, but in C++ a pointer to `refresh_list` is not permitted where a pointer to `dessert_per_result_t(void *, struct timeval *, struct timeval *)` is expected.

See also:

- [Understanding the difference between f() and f(void) in C and C++ once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13319492/1639256)
- [Is it better to use C void arguments "void foo(void)" or not "void foo()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/693788/1639256)

Comment: Edit: removed my all-too-clever solution, because you can't overload `extern "C"` functions :(