# Use the parameters of a function that takes any number of parameters, in C

Tags: c, parameters, variadic-functions

I've just read: ["C void arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments) about the differences between these function definitions in C:

```
int f(void)
```

and

```
int f()
```

Understanding that the second form means a function returning integer that takes any number of parameters, I wondered **how can we actually access and use these unknown parameters**?

I'd love to get sample code and explanation.

Also, I know the mechanism of the Varargs in C (with `va_arg`, `va_end`, `va_start` functions) and would be glad to hear about **the differences between this mechanism and the `f()` form** mentioned above.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: These are **function declarations**, not *definitions*; and you forgot the semicolon (i.e. it is `int f();` not just `int f()` alone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int f(void)` means a function returning int that takes no parameters.

You can see this example to see the consequence of using int f()

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f();

int main() {
  f(); /* prints some garbage */
  f(16);  /* prints 16 */ 
  return 0;
}

void f(a1)
  int a1;
{
   printf("%d\n", a1);
}
```

And also this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int f();
    int f(int x) {
        return x;
    }
    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
         printf ("%d\n", f(atoi(argv[1])));
         return 0;
    }

pax> gcc -Wall --std=c99 -o qq qq.c
pax> ./qq 42
42
```

Comment: Just happens to do that on your machine. In general, it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in particular for the `f(17,0)` call!!

Comment: Add example code for the case of declaring `void f(void)`, and your answer will be perfect :-)

Comment: Thank you! I've never seen this syntax: "void f(a1) int a1;". Is it a special syntax for this specific use?

Comment: @Reflection It's a deprecated K&R style. Commonly seen in programming books pre-1995-ish.

Answer (score 7):

The second version does *NOT* accept a variable number of parameters, it accepts a fixed (but unspecified) sequence of parameters. In effect, it declares the function, but does not *prototype* the function. So calls to the function will not be checked for valid types. It's common for the compiler to look at the first call to the function and check other calls against the types found in the first call.

This is why, if you omit `#include <stdio.h>`, the first call to `printf` will be acceptable, but any calls to `printf` with different types will generate an error. Eg.

```
int main() {
    printf("hello");        //<--- accepted, compiler may assume `int printf(char *);`
    printf("%s", "world");  //<--- error, type mismatch
}
```

To have a function accept a variable number, it must have at least one fixed parameter, and then the token `...`.

```
int f (int first, ...);
```

You will need to include the `stdarg.h` header file. And the function can access the parameters using macros.

```
void f (int c,...){
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, c);
    for(;c--;)
        printf("%d", va_arg(ap,int));
    va_end (ap);
}
```

It's convient to have the fixed argument be a count of the remaining arguments. You'll also need to determine the type of each argument somehow. In this example, they are assumed to all be `int`.

Comment: I would call it a *"fixed (unspecified) **sequence** of parameters"*  not a *set* of parameters (order obviously matters!).

Answer (score 4):

```
 int f(void);
```

declares `f` as a function taking no arguments and returning an `int` result, whereas

```
 int f();
```

declares `f` as a function taking a fixed but unspecified number and type of arguments (and, of course, returning an `int` result).

Given such a declaration, there has to be a *definition* somewhere that actually defines the parameters. If it takes no parameters, it might be defined as:

```
int f() {
    return 42;
};
```

If it takes 2 `int` parameters, it might be defined as:

```
int f(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Either definition is compatible with `int f();`, but only the first is compatible with `int f(void)`.

A function declaration that specifies the type(s) of the parameters, or, as a special case, uses the `void` keyword to specify that there are no parameters, is a *prototype*. A function declaration that *doesn't* do this, such as `int f();` is an old-style declaration.

Unless you're stuck using a decades-old pre-ANSI compiler that doesn't support prototypes, or you're maintaining very old code and don't have the time or other resources to update it, there is *no reason* not to use prototypes. If you call a function with no visible prototype, you still have to pass the correct number and type(s) of arguments; the difference is that the compiler will be unable to tell you if the call is incorrect.

(You can define a function that takes a variable number and type of arguments; `printf` is an example of this. This is done using the `, ...` notation. The function itself uses features defined in `<stdarg.h>` to process the arguments. But that has nothing to do with the declarations shown in your question.)

Here's a small program using obsolescent old-style function declarations and definitions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add();

int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    if (argc == 3) {
        /* NOTE: atoi() does no error checking */
        printf("sum = %d\n", add(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])));
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s x y\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int add(x, y)
int x, y;
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Note that if I had written `add(1, 2, 3, 4)` or `add("foo", "bar")`, the compiler wouldn't have caught the error; the program just would have misbehaved.

Here's an equivalent program using modern function declarations and definitions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 3) {
        /* NOTE: atoi() does no error checking */
        printf("sum = %d\n", add(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])));
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s x y\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

The visible prototype means that the compiler is able to diagnose incorrect calls.

Comment: I'm curious though, how would the compiler use the right calling convention if it doesn't know the parameter types of the function.

Comment: @newacct: **It doesn't**. Given a call with no visible prototype, the compiler *assumes* that the promoted arguments match the defined parameter types. If that assumption is invalid, then the call has undefined behavior. That's why you should always use prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

As to the `f()` form:
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319492/understanding-the-difference-between-f-and-fvoid-in-c-and-c-once-and-for-a).

An example, a printf-like function that can print decimal numbers or strings into a file descriptor:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
/* Formatted printing into a file descriptor */                          
int printfd(int fd, char *fmt, ...)                                      
{                                                                        
    int bytes = 0;                                                   
    int i_val = 0;                                                   
    va_list va;                                                      
    va_start(va, fmt);                                               
    while (*fmt) {                                                   
            char *perc = strchr(fmt, '%');                           
            int len = perc == NULL ? strlen(fmt) : perc - fmt;       
            if (len) {                                               
                    bytes += write(fd, fmt, len);                    
                    fmt += len;                                      
            } else {                                                 
                    fmt = perc + 1;                                  
                    if (*fmt == 0)                                   
                            continue;                                
                    else if (*fmt == '%')                            
                            bytes += write(fd, fmt, 1);              
                    else if (*fmt == 'd')                            
                            bytes += writedec(fd, va_arg(va, int));  
                    else if (*fmt == 's')                            
                            bytes += writestr(fd, va_arg(va, char*));
                    fmt++;                                           
            }                                                        
    }                                                                
    va_end(va);                                                      
    return bytes;                                                    
}
```

Comment: No, that does not answers the question!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Au Contraire. The title of this post suggest asker wants to know how to ***Use the parameters of a function that takes any number of parameters, in C***.  Perhaps the follow on questions confuse that original stated intent, but nonetheless this post answers it well.  +1 to SzG.