# Identifier list Vs Parameter type list in C

Tags: c, function

```
6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
```

This part of the standard deals with `'Identifier list'` and `'Parameter type list'`.

First of all, function declaration (not definition) is same as the function prototype. Am I correct? If this is right, then why the standard says `'including prototypes'`?

I am unable to understand the difference between `'Identifier list'` and `'Parameter type list'` with respect to function declaration.

```
int fun();    // Declaration
int fun(int x)// Definition, but the signature doesn't match and it works.
{ return x; }
```

Can someone explain, I am confused?

Comment: The problem what I am facing is, I am unable to follow the explanation given in standard. Bit difficult to understand the language.

Comment: Read: [Use the parameters of a function that takes any number of parameters, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18793193/1673391)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481579/whats-the-difference-between-function-prototype-and-declaration , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950642/why-does-a-function-with-no-parameters-compared-to-the-actual-function-definiti , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Function declaration is not the same as function prototype. Prototype is a special kind of declaration. For example, this is a function declaration that is not a prototype

```
int foo();
```

And the following declarations are prototypes

```
int foo(int a, double b);
int bar(char, float);
float baz(void);
```

I.e. prototype is a declaration that describes the number and the types of function parameters. A non-prototype declaration does not say anything about parameters.

Now, C language still supports old K&R-style function definitions in addition to "modern" function definitions. K&R-style function definition looks as follows

```
int foo(a, b)
int a;
double b;
{
  ...
}
```

A "modern" function definition looks as follows

```
int foo(int a, double b)
{
  ...
}
```

As you can see, the K&R-style parameter list is just `a, b`. It includes parameter names, but does not include their types. This is what the grammar refers to as *identifier-list*. The "modern" parameter list is `int a, double b` and this is what the grammar refers to as *parameter-type-list*.

I.e. *identifier-list* is a part of K&R-style function definition syntax, while *parameter-type-list* is a part of "modern" function definition syntax.

Note also that in C language the declaration

```
int foo();
```

does not mean that `foo` takes no arguments. It means that `foo` take an *unspecified* number of arguments, i.e. it simply turns off argument type checking, argument number checking and argument conversions for `foo` at the point of the call. Such "signature" will match a definition for `foo` with any parameter list. This

```
int foo(int x)
{
  ...
}
```

is a perfectly valid definition for `foo` declared as shown above. The fact that it is declared with `()` simply means that the compiler will not verify the arguments at the point of the call. It will be your responsibility to make sure that you are calling `foo` with exactly one argument of `int` type.

Comment: Worth noting: the declaration `foo()` prevents `float` and `char` arguments like `foo(float)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481579/whats-the-difference-between-function-prototype-and-declaration

Comment: Why doesn't composite types apply in such a situation, i mean between the declaration that specifies no arguments and the definition of the function `foo` so the compiler can deduce the prototype of the function and use it to check argument number and type at the moment of the call in the translation unit where only declaration without prototype is given ?

Answer (score 2):

In C11 standard

**6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
**Constraints**

```
D( parameter-type-list )
or
D( identifier-listopt )
```

While declaring function you need not give identifiers list. BUt you should at least mention type list

example:

```
int sum(int,int); //declaration  

int sum(int a,int b); //declaration
```

both are declaration of same function .

but second one you also mentioned identifiers that is optional.

Comment: Please note that both your declarations are examples of `D(parameter-type-list)`, _not_ `D(identifier-listopt)`. An example of a declaration that uses an identifier list would be `int sum(a, b)`. An identifier-list contains only identifiers, without types.

Answer (score 1):

> #### C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §6.2.1 *Scopes of identifiers* Section 2
>
> A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.

As of your example, for the function definition

```
int fun(int x)
{ return x; }
```

Both `int func(int x);` and `int func();` are valid function declarations. But only the former is a function prototype.

You can even omit the variable names in function declarations, e.g, `int func(int);`. Although we usually prefer not to do it because of lack of readability.