# How to find use of parameter-type-lists in a C code base?

Tags: c, parameters, function-declaration

I recently learned that there are [parameter-type-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820751/identifier-list-vs-parameter-type-list-in-c) which can be empty in C:

```
int print();

int main() {
    print("hallo");    //   << valid but highly unintuitive
}

int print() {
}
```

In this code someone might just have forgotten to write `print(void)` (maybe a C++ developer) but someone else provides a parameter. Compilation does not show any warnings or errors:

```
$ make test -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wall
cc     test.c   -o test
```

I didn't find a compiler flag which warns about empty parameter-type-lists, only about implicit function declaration.

Is there something I can do which helps me finding all uses of parameter-type-lists in a given code base?

E.g.

- [letting a C++ compiler compile the C code as C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/861556/1668622) and solve type issues (C++ does not allow arguments if the declaration does not list them)
- let the compiler list all function declarations (don't know if possible) and searching manually for empty braces
- `grep`ing for parameter-type-lists (too complex for me :))
- disabling parameter-type-lists via compiler switch (didn't find any)

Comment: You cannot compile C code with a C++ compiler! C++ is a different language and identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. C++ is **not** "C with classes"! And parameter-type-lists are exactly what you **have to** use for correct C. Everything else is outdated and deprecated since 17 years now. Not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/861556/1668622

Comment: you're right, but the differences to valid C++ code are exactly what I'm trying to find - the problem is I'll find much more issues than intended :)

Comment: That is far from what your questions asks. Maybe you have to think it over what your actual problem is and do some research first. There is enough material to be found by a simple search. FWIW: In C++ you also have to use parameter-type-lists (the name and the complete grammar might differ due to C++ being more complex, but that's basically the same thing).

Comment: Oh, and the first linked question is not a citation from the C standard.

Comment: Perhaps I understand you wrongly, so please correct me if I do, but I guess you want to get rid of declarations like `int fun(a, b) int a; float b; {`. Right? Then you don't want to get rid of parameter type lists, you want to get rid of old style K&R identifier lists.

Comment: I want to get rid of ambiguous declarations like `void foo()` which can be called with arguments (like `x = foo(4)`)

Comment: @frans please edit your question and show some examples of what exactly you want to find and get rid of and show also some examples of what would be OK.

Comment: If all you need to do is identify function definitions where there is an empty argument list `()` and you want to replace it with `(void)`, then you can usually create heuristic scans to do the job based on the normal layout of such functions in your code.  If your code base is anarchic (aka normal), then there'll be variants with spaces between the parentheses.  If you use 1TBS, there may be zero or more spaces between the `()` and `{`.  Etc. If you want to find erroneous calls to functions that take no arguments, make sure there's always a prototype in scope (that says `(void)`) and compile.

Comment: @frans, the make invocation example you added to your question shows the compiler *not* using the warning options you specify on the `make` command line, as indeed I would expect.  You need to modify your makefile to cause it to use the options, or possibly to specify the options to `make` as the value of a macro that the makefile uses, such as `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, running `gcc` directly shows the warnings

Answer (score 2):

With gcc, using *-Wstrict-prototypes* will achieve what you expect:

> -Wstrict-prototypes (C and Objective-C only)
>   Warn if a function is declared or defined without specifying the argument types. (An old-style function definition is permitted without a warning if preceded by a declaration that specifies the argument types.)

With your example, it gives:

```
hallo.c:1:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int print() {
     ^
```

However, you'll have to ensure that all non-strict function declarations in your existing code gets properly defined; in particular, functions without parameters should be declared with *(void)*, like this:

```
 int print(void);
```

Comment: That's good if the OP is using GCC, but not complete.  If there is no declaration of function `print()` in scope at all then there is nothing for `-Wstrict-prototypes` to warn about.

Comment: But I'll get warned about `int print() {..}` (without void) and together with `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` I *have* to provide a full prototype. When I want to call `print("hello");`

Answer (score 1):

Your example is *not* valid, neither in C nor in C++.  Since your `print()` function does not accept any parameters -- which is well established from the function *definition* you provide (C2011, 6.7.6.3/14) -- it is non-conforming to call it with an argument, regardless of whether a prototype is visible at the point of the call (C2011, 6.5.2.2/6).  If the call appears in a scope wherein neither the function definition nor any *bona fide* prototype is visible then the compiler might nevertheless accept the code, but that does not make it valid or guarantee that it will work.

Additionally, you seem to be using the wrong term, or possibly your idea is very wrong-headed.  Parameter-type-lists are the modern way of declaring (and defining) functions, including function prototypes:

```
int my_func(int a, char *b);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----- parameter-type-list
```

You should **not** get rid of those, but I think you mean that you want to identify and fix K&R-style function definitions and also function declarations *without* parameter-type-lists.  (The formal syntax's terms for the K&R style are "identifier list" and, if needed, an accompanying "declaration list".)

As for identifying the occurrences of K&R-style declarations automatically, that's a job for a C language parser, and the most common implementations of those are C compilers.  Your compiler may have an option for just what you want.  GCC, for example, has options `-Wstrict-prototypes` and `-Wold-style-defintion`, which, together, will signal both function declarations that are not prototypes and K&R-style function definitions.  GCC has some other options that might be of interest to you too, such as `-Wimplicit`, `-Wtraditional`, and `-Wc++-compat`.

Comment: Well, your answer sounds profound so maybe I don't get the point. My problem is that the compiler **does** accept `void print() {..}` and calling it with arguments. Maybe my wording is wrong..

Comment: @frans, if your compiler accepts the function call with an argument, even though the function definition does not specify any parameters, then either there is no prototype for that function in scope at the point of the call, or the compiler is buggy.  If you are using GCC, then it will warn about calls to undeclared functions if you use `-Wimplicit` (or `-Wall`).  In that case, if you also use `-Wstrict-prototypes` then GCC will flag function declarations that do not provide prototypes.  With that combination, your code should not get past GCC without eliciting some kind of diagnostic.

Comment: have you actually tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950800/1668622 suggests that it's obsolescent but valid. `-Wstrict-prototypes` finds what I'm looking for so your answer *contains* the solution but tells something different..

Comment: @frans, Have I actually tried *what*?  Every conforming C compiler accepts function declarations and function definitions with (possibly empty) identifier lists and corresponding declaration lists (i.e. K&R style).  Although that form is obsolescent, it is still in the standard, and failing to accept such declarations would, in itself, make a compiler non-conforming.  Of course, emitting warnings is not the same thing as rejecting the code.

Comment: @frans, note also that `-Wstrict-prototypes` is not necessarily sufficient to flag all function calls with the wrong number or type of arguments.  In fact, it doesn't directly warn about bad calls at all.  It warns about declarations that are not prototypes, and once a correct prototype is in place, the compiler will warn about the bad call.  But it is possible for there to be no function declaration in scope at the point of the call at all, in which case the call will get through unnoticed unless you enable warnings about *that*, too (i.e. `-Wimplicit`).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to look for is `()` (with optional whitespace), followed by `{` (with optional whitespace, perhaps newline).  And you can replace it with `(void)`.

If you want an "industrial grade" solution you can use a compiler which emits something easier to parse, such as [GCC-XML](http://gccxml.github.io/) or [Clang](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/tools/clang/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html).

Comment: This would definitively be an answer if there was an example. And it's the second and third approach I've listed in my question. But since there can be spaces and newlines everywhere, this leads to regex/escape hell for me.