# Difference between identifier list and parameter list in function?

Tags: c, function, declaration, definition

For this quote:

> An identifier list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function shall be empty.

what is the difference between identifier list and parameter list and can someone provide an example for this quote.

Comment: It would be useful to specify which section of which document you are using, when you give standard quotes.

Comment: it is 6.7.5.3/3

Comment: i think you can find your answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820751/identifier-list-vs-parameter-type-list-in-c

Comment: this is the half of the answer read the question.

Comment: @Sabrina there is no 6.7.5.3 in the current standard. Which is why I suggested specifying which document you are reading. You must have some old standard.

Comment: really my file is C99 standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "identifier list" is only used in obsolete "K&R style" functions.  New code written today would never use it. You can see more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092074/4323

It's something like this:

```
void func(identifier-list)
declaration-list
{
    body
}
```

When they say it shall be empty, they mean that even admitting the possibility of ancient code, you are not allowed to have this in a declaration which does not define a function.  So for example this is not allowed:

```
void func(x) int x;
```

Comment: What about `shall be empty` ?

Comment: It is the opposite switch them .

Comment: @Sabrina that's pretty clear isn't it? "shall be empty" means there cannot be anything in between the parentheses, for a declaration that is not a definition. So you cannot write `void func(x);`

Comment: @M.M so the quote is only restricted to old style.( K&R )

Comment: The standard is written this way because the grammar rules for function declarations treat `func()` as having an empty identifier-list between the parentheses.  So identifier-lists have to be allowed in function declarations ... but only if they are empty.

Answer (score 2):

Identifier list without identifiers' definitions says nothing about the types of function parameters. So it does not make sense to specify an identifier list for a function declaration when it is not at the same time a function definition.

So this restriction of the cited quote is used.

Here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f();

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    f( x );

    return 0;
}

void f( x ) 
int x;
{
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}
```

When a parameter list is used the compiler can check a call of a function that valid arguments are passed to the function. So it is better always to use parameter list instead of identifier list.