# Consistency between a function's declaration in a C header and its definition in a .cpp file

Tags: c++, c, void

Consider a C++ function that I want to interface it in C (e.g., `int foo()`) that takes no input arguments.

The lack of input arguments in C can be expressed as `int foo(void);`, while `int foo()` in C means arbitrary number of input arguments.

However, in C++ `int foo()` means a function that takes no arguments and `int foo(void)` is considered a C backward compatibility remnant that should be avoided.

Considering the above, what's the most proper?

> **Option 1:**
>
> > C header declaration : `int foo(void);`
> >
> > C++ file definition   : `int foo(void) { ... }`
>
> **Option 2:**
>
> > C header declaration : `int foo();`
> >
> > C++ file definition   : `int foo() { ... }`
>
> **Option 3:**
>
> > C header declaration : `int foo(void);`
> >
> > C++ file definition   : `int foo() { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, we already know the difference between [`f()` and `f(void)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319492/understanding-the-difference-between-f-and-fvoid-in-c-and-c-once-and-for-a) in C and C++.

Since using `f()` is bad practice in C (you lose the compiler's ability to compare the function's declaration to its definition, to ensure that it will be called correctly) and you have C linkage for that function, I'd advise to use `f(void)`

After all, **in c++, `f(void)` was only kept alive to have backwards combatibility with C**, which is exactly your use case.

---

Just a minor correction : It's not arbitrary number of input arguments but **unspecified** meaning that's there's a serious difference to variadic functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
// Header
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void foo(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And for cpp file:

```
// in cpp file
extern "C" {
    void foo(void)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

As we explicitly show that we use C.